# Regex help in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large string that may have some items I want to retrieve out of it.

An example string could be

```
"The quick |Get Me|(header1) brown fox |Get Me|(info package) jumps over ..."
```

I would like a regex to extract what is in between the brackets, not including the brackets and the brackets will always follow `"|Get Me|"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern that will match:

```
\|Get Me\|\(([^)]+)\)
```

Usage:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, @"\|Get Me\|\(([^)]+)\)");

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
   var val = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: +1 That does it, but just so Robert knows, it matches the whole |Get Me|(header1) string, and then you extract the header1 part using  the matches' groups.

Comment: Yes that does do it,  somehow and yes I needed to get a string out of a group collection. It's amazing and baffling thanks very much

Comment: @RobertHancliff - I suggest you read [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/). You will be much less baffled and start understanding regex to a good degree.

Comment: @RobertHancliff ... and experiment using the .NET Regex Tester at http://regexhero.net (personal non-affiliated recommendation)